# ArcPy - Module error

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase

I’m trying to use the ArcPy Python module to create a geodatabase to store information.
I am currently running ArcPy in Visual Studio on a Windows 10 machine.

The function I am trying to use is:

`arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(out_folder_path, out_name, {out_version})`

With following inputs defined as:

```py
out_folder_path = 'C:/FILEPATH',
out_name = "geodatabase.gdb",
out_version = '10.0'
```

When I run the function I receive the following error

> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23214, in CreateFileGDB
>
> raise e
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23211, in CreateFileGDB
>
> retval =
> convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateFileGDB_management(*gp_fixargs((out_folder_path, out_name, out_version), True)))
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 512, in
>
> return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
> RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

PS C:\Users\USER

I have set up ArcPy on my PC in Visual Studio, I receive the following error upon running it which may be related however this does not seem to impact the module for other functions:

> PS C:\Users\USER> conda activate arcgispro-py3
> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - conda activate arcgispro-py3
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

As a first start I would try to run your code in the Python console within ArcGIS Pro. If that runs as expected it would at least confirm the arcpy installation is OK. Then search the Esri website on how to set up visual studio correctly. I don't use Visual Studio, I use the spyder IDE which integrates seamlessly with ArcGIS Pro. I put a document together at [Installing spyder IDE for ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-blog/installing-spyder-ide-for-arcpro/ba-p/901923) if you are interested.